# App Rejected By App Store due to Subscription in app

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift3, in-app-purchase, subscription

This is the text from AppStore for Rejection.

> We noticed that your app offers a subscription with a mechanism other than the in-app purchase API.

Actually app is not having any third party for payment or no any In app purchase but if i searched for `InAppPurchase` OR `Subscription` word in project then i can found methods inside the `FBSDKLoginKit` and `FBSDKCoreKit`.

In App Purchase is OFF in Capabilities.

In App Purchase is ON in Certificates. (Which is by default ON)

But They are saying we are offering subscription other than In app purchase which is actually not there.

Does any one have solution of this type of issue?

Please help guys!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You need to resubmit to Apple for review and mention that App does not have any Subscription/In App purchase, and that you are using Facebook SDK that has subscription support but you are not using that feature in your app.

I'm not sure if this will successfully make your application pass the review process but it may help

Comment: Thanks!

We have already make it through Resolution Center! :D

Comment: Great!
Please mention the reason you gave? so that if someone facing same could get help.